# Full Calendar V5 Scroll to Current Day Using Hook (Callback After Entire View is rendered)

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using fullcalendar v5 and I'm trying to scroll the window to the current day element using the viewDidMount hook. It finds the element via "fc-day-today" class, but when calling scrollIntoView, nothing happens.

Full calendar option (registering method on the hook):

```
viewDidMount: this.scrollToCurrentDay,
```

My code to scroll:

```
// scrollToCurrentDay

var element = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-day-today');
element[0].scrollIntoView();
```

If I wrap the scrollIntoView() call in a timeout, then it works, but I don't want to do this since it seems hacky.

Is there a callback/hook called AFTER THE ENTIRE FULLCALENDAR VEIW RENDERS that I can listen to?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Full Calendar specifically, and what you used already seems to be the documented way to do this, but alternatively, you could use a more event based approach with a mutation observer on the calendar element.

```js
const calendarElement = document.getElementById('calendar');

const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  // the mutation target should be something like "div.fc-day-today"
  console.log(mutations);
});

mutationObserver.observe(calendarElement, {
  subtree: true, // Will trigger for child elements
  attributes: true
});

const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarElement, {
  initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
});
calendar.render();
```

Obviously, there may be a better element to hook on to based on what you see happening in your app.

Here is a reference to the MDN "mutation record" spec for convenience : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord

Comment: Thanks - so this mutation observer would actually allow me to find when the today element rendered on screen and apply logic thereafter?

Comment: More specifically, when it's added to the DOM. I make this distinction because it could be added and "hidden" for example. The above example catches all mutations for all childs of the 'calendar' element, so yes, you can look for the exact one you want then call "scrollIntoView", though there is a good chance that the first mutation involving the today element will be the correct moment to call it.